# Broken grub rescue,due to corrupt Linux partition

Tags: dual-boot

I accidentally changed my hard disk partition to be mounted only after authorization, but when I restarted my laptop grub was corrupted, I think it is not loading the os partitions.

How to recover this mounting problem?

Note: running `ls` in Grub rescue window result with:

```
(hd0) , (hd0,msdos4),(hd0,msdos2),(hdo,msdos1)
```

Comment: when i did the ls command in Grub rescue window i got this..(hd0) , (hd0,msdos4),(hd0,msdos2),(hdo,msdos1).

Answer (score 0):

I usually perform grub repair operations from a live CD. I am making the assumption that your HDD uses MBR structure. If you use EUFI and GPT, this will not work.

Boot into a live Ubuntu CD, select Try Ubuntu, NOT Install Ubuntu.

Open a terminal and mount your OS partition (lets assume it is /dev/sda1).

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Install grub to the MBR of /dev/sda and tell it to use existing /dev/sda1 grub config

```
sudo grub2-install /dev/sda --boot-directory=/mnt/boot
```

You should see a message indicating grub is installed and no errors are reported.

Reboot.